# Read all sms exist in GSM Modem in c# app

Tags: c#, sms, gsm

I wrote this code to receive sms.but if some sms receive with together,it can not show all of them. How can i read all of sms?

```
 private GSMModem oGsmModem
        {
            get { return withEventsField_oGsmModem; }
            set
            {
                if (withEventsField_oGsmModem != null)
                {
                    withEventsField_oGsmModem.NewMessageReceived -= oGsmModem_NewMessageReceived;
                }
                withEventsField_oGsmModem = value;
                if (withEventsField_oGsmModem != null)
                {
                    withEventsField_oGsmModem.NewMessageReceived += oGsmModem_NewMessageReceived;
                }
            }

        }

 private void oGsmModem_NewMessageReceived(ATSMS.NewMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            txtMsg.Text = "Message from " + e.MSISDN + ". Message - " + e.TextMessage ;
        }
```

Comment: This event occurs only when new message comes.
Please check all the properties and methods of GSMModem class for getting all the messages.
Is this GSMModem class developd by you or a third party class?

Comment: GSMModem class developd by  a third party,Now how do i do?

Comment: Check all the properties and methods of GSMModem class.
Do you have any link for that User Manual of GSMModem class?

Comment: dont u have a GSMModem class?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [SMS AT Communication Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/atsms/) from sourceforge

See the MessageStore property of your oGsmModem object for all messages.
Hint: Use Refresh to reload from modem.